# What does -_ mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I'm reading source code of some Scala App, I always see such expression `val sortedWithId = scores.data.zipWithIndex.sortBy(-_._1)`.

What does -_ mean?

You know it's so hard to google this kind of expression, so if anyone knows, could you give me some examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually 3 parts in `-_._1`

- The minus sign '-' which changes the sign of `_._1` (see Jörg comment below for all details)
- The placeholder parameter for the anonymous function `_`, writing `_._1` is the same as writing `x => x._1`
- The access to the first element of the tuple passed as parameter `_1`

`-_._1` is actually passing an anonymous function that returns the negative of the first element of the tuple passed as parameter, and could otherwise be written: `w => - w._1`

Comment: Thanks so much! The first - simply means negative, that confused me.

Comment: Actually, the first `-` is the unary prefix `-` operator, which is simply syntactic sugar for the `unary_-` method, and since it is just a method like any other method, it can do anything it wants to. `Int.unary_-`, `Long.unary_-` etc. perform negation, but there is nothing which says that every class in the universe must do so. For example, I can imagine an internal DSL for constructing shell commands to overload it in such a way that you can write stuff like `foo -bar, -baz` or something like that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the precision